# How can I test uploading a file using dropzone.js from protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, dropzone.js

I am attempting to test a Dropzone.js form using Protractor. [This method of uploading to a file input using Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21314337/1023812) is not working for me.

Dropzone does create a hidden `<input type="file">` element to handle the upload, but when I `sendKeys` to it, I get the error:

> Server responded with 0 code.

It also shows that 0 bytes were sent. I opened up Charles and confirmed that no `POST` request is made to the upload route defined on my dropzone form.

I found [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880524/how-do-you-test-uploading-a-file-with-capybara-and-dropzone), which suggests adding a second `<input type="file">` and then creating a drop event, but I don't have a `window` element when running Protractor tests, so I'm not really sure that it translates.

How can I trigger a Dropzone.js upload in a Protractor/Jasmine test session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I have posted a question looking for the wrong answer. There is nothing special about Dropzone. Just make sure that the path you are sending to the `<input type="file">` element points to an actual file. It works fine.