# How to test React Dropzone with Capybara Rails 5.2

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5.2, react-dropzone

I'm trying to test file upload in Capybara, Rails 5.2 feature spec with selenium.

I have been searching for this and found a couple of suggestions. One of them is [How do you test uploading a file with Capybara and Dropzone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880524/how-do-you-test-uploading-a-file-with-capybara-and-dropzone-js)

However, these solutions are for jQuery and Dropzone.js. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% of the time passing `visible: false` as an option to `find` indicates you're doing something wrong when testing applications with Capybara.

If all you were trying to do is upload a file when the file input is hidden for styling reasons then the Capybara docs provide all the needed info - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method - and an option specifically for dealing with this situation

```
attach_file(Rails.root.join('spec', 'resources', 'test.png'), make_visible: true)
```

Comment: If the 99% was correct, I might be in the 1%. I have tested with react-dropzone and it worked. Also the implementation of react-dropzone makes it hidden.

Comment: @TrongBang You're not, and just because it "works" doesn't make it the right way to do it - you're just lucky that you chose to use selenium with chromedriver as your driver, which happens to currently not follow the webdriver spec and lets you send keys at non-visible file field elements (which a user could never do)

Comment: so do you have a solution to this? with the current implementation of react-dropzone, probably you would need to use javascript to make it visible and then use attach_file() method. Any other guess?

Comment: I confirmed the code works as expected. Can you please explain the point why visible: false mostly is wrong? the attach_file() also uses make_visible: true. What is the difference? Thanks

Comment: @TrongBang It's wrong because using `find(..., visible: false).send_keys ...` will fail with most drivers since they (correctly) wont let you interact with non-visible elements (user wouldn't be able to).  The general use of `visible: false` is wrong because a user can't see/interact with the elements and thus they are irrelevant to testing an app from a users perspective.  The `make_visible` option to `attach_file` handles, in a multi-driver compatible way, the one common case where it isn't currently possible to do things the way a user would/could.

Comment: I hope you dont get this in a wrong way. From the documentation: 

make_visible (true, Hash) — A Hash of CSS styles to change before attempting to attach the file, if `true` { opacity: 1, display: 'block', visibility: 'visible' } is used (may not be supported by all drivers)

I guess it's a trick to make it visible right?

Comment: @TrongBang It's not a "trick", it is a supported feature of Capybara that temporarily makes the element visible (hence the name `make_visible`)

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to below may well solve your problem

```rb
find(".dropzone").drop(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/file.txt"))
```

Answer (score -1):

the magic code:

```
        find('input[type="file"]', visible: false).send_keys \
            Rails.root.join('spec', 'resources', 'test.png')
```